# Switch branch in TFS when executing tests from Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, tfs, branch

If I have multiple branches in TFS for my automation code (QA branch, Beta branch, Live branch, etc.), is there a way to switch the branch being used when executing the tests via Jenkins?

I use Eclipse IDE and have multiple Maven projects set up in Jenkins that execute my tests. We use TFS as our source control at the moment.

I have different automation branches due to code base differences between environments and would like to be able to specify the automation code branch to use depending on what environment is being ran against on build time in Jenkins.

I am using a Choice Parameter for the environment. If I could set another variable off of that, maybe something like if env.contains("Dev") then set branchPath="QA" and then use the branchPath as the Project path in Source Code Management?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: Currently we are using TFVC. There has been talk of moving to Git, but there is no timeline on that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the project path in Source Code Management section of Jenkin, in Project path, you can specify the branch you need:

[image]

Comment: But is there a way to use a variable of some sort here? I am using a Choice Parameter for the environment. If I could set another variable off of that, maybe something like if env.contains("Dev") then set branchPath="QA" and then use the branchPath as the Project path?

Comment: You would need to get help from Jenkins side to see whether it supports variables.